# AngularJs Datatables not able to iterate columns on html using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-datatables

Hi I am working on Angularjs Datatables and trying to iterate the   columns and rows using ng-repeat but its not working. I checked the document but not able to find the exact way to pass columns and records on html.

```
function CustomElementCtrl(DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {  
    var vm = this;  
    vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource('data.json')  
        .withDOM('&lt;"custom-element"&gt;pitrfl');  
    vm.dtColumns = [  
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('ID'),  
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('firstName').withTitle('First name'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('lastName').withTitle('Last name').notVisible()
    ];
}
Here the dtColumns are manually created and the dtOptions are directly assigned from json, but I want to assign columns also from json.
And why I can't use ng-repeat on html to iterate both columns and rows
rather then like this <table datatable="" dt-options="showCase.dtOptions"   dt-columns="showCase.dtColumns" class="row-border hover">
```

Thanks,

Comment: where you have used ng-repeat? and where have you assigned data to scope?

Comment: @KishoreBarik On html like  
<table datatable=""  class="row-border hover">
<thead><tr><th ng-repeat="column in columns">{{column}}</th></tr></thead>
<tbody><tr ng-repeat="record in records"><td>{{record.name}}</td><td>{{record.date}}</td></tr></tbody></table>  

and on controller $scope.columns = resoponse.data;
$scope.records = response.data;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Angular way to bind the date
your table must be like this

```
<table datatable="ng" class="row-border hover"></table>
```

as per [docs.](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#/angularWayWithOptions)

Comment: Welcome to SO! When posting solutions to people's questions, it is important to include all the information in any link you include

Comment: @MayorMonty What do you mean by all the information ?